# Calling Functions with Vectors

Tags: c++, function, vector

I'm still a beginner with C++ but I am having some coding trouble.

I have already defined the function void AskMenuChoice(vector &choice, int *pIndex) but I don't exactly know the correct syntax for calling it to Main.cpp.

Anyone know how to explain this as simple as possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you intend for the index chosen to be returned through the parameter `pIndex`, in which case what you need to do is create an integer in your calling function and pass the address of this variable to this function.

```
std::vector<Choice> choices = /* however you're making your choices */;
int chosen;
AskMenuChoice(choices, &chosen);
std::cout << "Option " << chosen << " was picked." << std::endl;
```

This is sort of an awkward way to do this though, and it would be better to instead *return* the value from `AskMenuChoice`. This would change the signature of the function to `int AskMenuChoice(vector& choices)` and usage to:

```
std::vector<Choice> choices = /* however you're making your choices */;
int chosen = AskMenuChoice(choices);
std::cout << "Option " << chosen << " was picked." << std::endl;
```